# issubclass that returns False when passing an instance instead of a class

Tags: python, class, subclass

I would like to get `issubclass` to work as follows: if the original `issubclass` receives an instance instead of a class, it just return False. Do I need to write a similar function like the one below or is there a nicer way how to do that?

```
def my_issubclass(cls, parent):
    try:
        return issubclass(cls, parent)
    except: # issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
        return False
```

Comment: You can check upfront if `cls` is actually a class (`isinstance(cls, type)`) but that's a matter of [EAFP vs LBYL](https://medium.com/@sunken/eafp-versus-lbyl-which-one-should-we-use-in-python-ff644abe09dc) philosophy. Can't do much more than that, I'm not sure why would you want to anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`issubclass()` is designed to raise an exception when the first argument is not a class, so yes, it'll raise `TypeError` if you pass in something else. That's because in most contexts, mixing classes (types) and instances would indicate a bug somewhere!

So your options are to catch that exception (and **just** that exception, don't play Pokemon here, you don't want to catch them all):

```
def my_issubclass(obj, type_or_types):
    try:
        return issubclass(obj, type_or_types)
    except TypeError:  # issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
        return False
```

or you could first check if you actually have a class:

```
def my_issubclass(obj, type_or_types):
    return isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, type_or_types)
```

The first form is called *Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than it is for Permission* or EAFP, and the second is *Look Before You Leap*, LBYL. Which one you pick is based, in part, on style preference, and in part on performance considerations. If you don't use it all that often with an instance instead of a class, then use the first form, otherwise use the second. See my answer to [*Python Forgiveness vs. Permission and Duck Typing*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing/175663#175663) over on Software Engineering.

Quick demo with `bool` and `int` (yes, the boolean type is a subclass of integers):

```
>>> def my_issubclass_eafp(obj, type_or_types):
...     try:
...         return issubclass(obj, type_or_types)
...     except TypeError:  # issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
...         return False
...
>>> def my_issubclass_lbyl(obj, type_or_types):
...     return isinstance(obj, type) and issubclass(obj, type_or_types)
...
>>> my_issubclass_eafp(1, int)
False
>>> my_issubclass_eafp(bool, int)
True
>>> my_issubclass_lbyl(1, int)
False
>>> my_issubclass_lbyl(bool, int)
True
```